# What is "an agreeable succession of long and short syllables"?

Tags: classical-latin, vowel-quantity

I am currently (re)reading Allen and Greenough's Latin Grammar and I am somewhat confused by the [end of paragraph 601](https://dcc.dickinson.edu/grammar/latin/structure-period) on the structure of the Period.

> **f.** The Romans were careful to close a period with an agreeable succession of long and short syllables.
>
> > ***Quod scīs nihil prōdest, quod nescīs multum obest.*** (Or. 166) *What you know is of no use, what you do not know does great harm.*

What is "an agreeable succession of long and short syllables"?

Answer (score 5):

I assume this is a reference to the concept of a "[clausula](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Clausula_(rhetoric))". I'm not familiar with this topic, but per Wikipedia, research has been done showing that different Latin authors prefer to end their sentences with different rhythms.